# How to create a web-based Email Client in .NET?

Tags: .net, email, pop3

I am creating a web based email client in .NET using a 3rd party component.

I just want to make sure I have the right idea:

1. I will first pull the emails in using POP
2. I will then parse each individual message that I got from POP using the MIME component right?

My choices for 3rd party are: **Nsoftware, Quiksoft or Dart.**

I am looking at Nsoftware right now though.

Comment: Edited to make a question that can have a detailed answer.  The question was too specific, wanted to make it more general.

Comment: trying out nsoftware right now John.

Answer (score 2):

I attempted a similar project last year, but never got very far with it.  There were so many solid off-the-shelf solutions to this that I took the advice "Programming is hard. Let's go shopping!"

Comment: which ones are you referring to?

Comment: SquirrelMail and Horde both seemed to fit what I needed to do.

Answer (score -1):

Using the /n software POP and MIME component, you are correct. You would use the POP component to retrieve your message, then use the MIME component to decode the message into its constituent parts. /n software provides examples with their IP*Works product on using the POP and MIME components. If you need further help, their support team is top notch.

Comment: Found a link to the trial version of IP*Works [Trial](http://nsoftware.com/download/download.aspx?part=IPN8-A&prod=demo&type=exe)